# CUDA Unified Memory: Difference in behaviour on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, cuda

I am porting an application from Linux to Windows and discovered significant runtime differences of the same code on the same hardware between Windows and Linux.

A minimal working example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cuda.h>

constexpr unsigned int MB = 1000000;
constexpr unsigned int num_bytes = 20 * MB;
constexpr unsigned int repeats = 50;

constexpr unsigned int the_answer = 42;
constexpr unsigned int half_of_the_answer = the_answer / 2;
constexpr unsigned int array_index = 100;


__global__ void kernel(uint8_t* data){
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i<num_bytes){
        data[i] = half_of_the_answer;
    }
}

void doSomethingOnGPU(uint8_t* data){
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
    cudaStreamAttachMemAsync(stream, data, 0, cudaMemAttachSingle);

    kernel<<<num_bytes/1000, 1000, 0, stream>>>(data);

    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}


void doSomethingOnCPU(uint8_t* pic_unpacked){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < num_bytes; i++){
        pic_unpacked[i] = the_answer;
    }
}

int main() {
    uint8_t* data{};
    cudaMallocManaged(&data, num_bytes, cudaMemAttachHost);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<repeats;i++){
        auto start_time_cpu = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        doSomethingOnCPU(data);

        auto stop_time_cpu = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration_cpu = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop_time_cpu-start_time_cpu);

        std::cout << "CPU computation took "<< duration_cpu.count() << "ms, data[" << array_index << "]="
                  << static_cast<unsigned int>(data[array_index]) << std::endl;


        auto start_time_gpu = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        doSomethingOnGPU(data);

        auto stop_time_gpu = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration_gpu = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop_time_gpu-start_time_gpu);

        std::cout << "GPU computation took "<< duration_gpu.count() << "ms, data[" << array_index << "]="
                  << static_cast<unsigned int>(data[array_index]) << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    cudaFree(data);
    return 0;
}
```

This leads to the following output on Windows:

```
CPU computation took 216ms, data[100]=42
GPU computation took 29ms, data[100]=21
```

and to the following output on Linux:

```
CPU computation took 20ms, data[100]=42
GPU computation took 1ms, data[100]=21
```

Both are built in Release mode (Linux->GCC, Win->MSVC).

It seems to me, that the automatic memory transfers do not work well under Windows.

Explicit memory transfers with

```cpp
cudaMallocHost(&hostMem, size);
cudaMalloc(&cudaMem, size);
cudaMemcpy(hostMem, cudaMem, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(cudaMem, hostMem, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

work more or less with the same speed under Linux and Windows.

Why is there this big runtime difference between Linux and Windows when working with unified memory?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements). I would guess the performance difference is due to the lack of support for on-demand page migration under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements):

> GPUs with SM architecture 6.x or higher (Pascal class or newer) provide additional Unified Memory features such as on-demand page migration and GPU memory oversubscription. [...] Applications running on Windows (whether in TCC or WDDM mode) will use the basic Unified Memory model as on pre-6.x architectures even when they are running on hardware with compute capability 6.x or higher.

Of the features explicitly mentioned here, I would think that "on-demand page migration" is very relevant for the increased performance under Linux.