# Passing a struct type vector from CPU to GPU in CUDA

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I have a struct named IntensityVal.

```
struct IntensityVal
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int bpp;
    BYTE* pImgBuf; //Store buffer of a RGB image
};
```

And a vector `std::vector<IntensityVal>IntensityMat;`. I want to pass this vector in a CUDA kernel. How can I do this?

I tried this solution but gives an "Access violation error" in Visual Studio 2019.

```
IntensityVal* deviceIntensityMat;
cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceIntensityMat, IntensityMat.size() * sizeof(IntensityVal));

for (size_t i = 0; i < IntensityMat.size(); ++i) {
    int imgBufSize = IntensityMat[i].width * IntensityMat[i].height * (IntensityMat[i].bpp / 8);
    BYTE* deviceImgBuf;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceImgBuf, imgBufSize);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceImgBuf, IntensityMat[i].pImgBuf, imgBufSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //Error giving in this line
    
    // Copy the structure to the device
    IntensityVal temp = { IntensityMat[i].width, IntensityMat[i].height, IntensityMat[i].bpp, deviceImgBuf };
    cudaMemcpy(&deviceIntensityMat[i], &temp, sizeof(IntensityVal), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }
```

Also, frees the allocated memory in GPU.

Comment: Access violation is a host side memory error. That probably means `IntensityMat[i].pImgBuf` isn’t correctly initialised.

Comment: The standard answer is [cudaMallocManaged](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/). Although you should also consider whether the GPU even needs that header. Looks more like you should pass that as a kernel launch parameter and give the GPU only the raw bytes. But that's just a suggestion based on incomplete code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy an object to device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024087/copy-an-object-to-device)

Comment: @talonmies I have checked my host side vector and it is populated perfectly. It contains values of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll spell it out some more compared to the comments.

The issue with your code is that you try to write to an object that you allocated *on the GPU*. This does not work. There are two options:

1. Use managed allocations

These can be accessed by both the GPU and CPU. There are peculiarities about their performance, which are discussed in this blog post: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/

```cpp
IntensityVal* deviceIntensityMat;
cudaMallocManaged(&deviceIntensityMat,
      IntensityMat.size() * sizeof(IntensityVal));

for (size_t i = 0; i < IntensityMat.size(); ++i) {
    int imgBufSize = IntensityMat[i].width * IntensityMat[i].height
          * (IntensityMat[i].bpp / 8);
    BYTE* deviceImgBuf;
    cudaMalloc(&deviceImgBuf, imgBufSize);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceImgBuf, IntensityMat[i].pImgBuf, imgBufSize,
          cudaMemcpyDefault);
    
    // Copy the structure to the device-visible array
    deviceIntensityMat[i] = {
          IntensityMat[i].width, IntensityMat[i].height,
          IntensityMat[i].bpp, deviceImgBuf };
}
// prefetch to GPU once the CPU is done with it. Optional
int currentDevice;
cudaGetDevice(&currentDevice);
cudaMemPrefetchAsync(deviceIntensityMat,
      IntensityMat.size() * sizeof(IntensityVal), currentDevice);
```

2. Initialize the structure from the inside out on the GPU, using an intermediate array of host-accessible memory pointing at device-memory

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<IntensityVal[]> hostDeviceIntensityMat =
      std::make_unique<IntensityVal[]>(IntensityMat.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < IntensityMat.size(); ++i) {
    int imgBufSize = IntensityMat[i].width * IntensityMat[i].height *
          (IntensityMat[i].bpp / 8);
    BYTE* deviceImgBuf;
    cudaMalloc(&deviceImgBuf, imgBufSize);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceImgBuf, IntensityMat[i].pImgBuf, imgBufSize,
          cudaMemcpyDefault);
    // prepare host-visible array for copy later
    hostDeviceIntensityMat[i] = {
          IntensityMat[i].width, IntensityMat[i].height,
          IntensityMat[i].bpp, deviceImgBuf };
}
// copy array of arrays to GPU
IntensityVal* deviceIntensityMat;
cudaMalloc(&deviceIntensityMat,
      IntensityMat.size() * sizeof(IntensityVal));
cudaMemcpy(deviceIntensityMat, hostDeviceIntensityMat.get(),
      IntensityMat.size() * sizeof(IntensityVal), cudaMemcpyDefault);
```

Side-notes:

1. I've omitted proper error checking just like you. See [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)
2. You may want to consider [pitched allocations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c) for your images, see [How and when should I use pitched pointer with the cuda API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119943/how-and-when-should-i-use-pitched-pointer-with-the-cuda-api/16119944#16119944)
3. All of these memcpys will have poor performance since they don't use pinned allocations and none of them happen asynchronously in a stream. Refer to the Best Practice Guide section [9.1. Data Transfer Between Host and Device](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#data-transfer-between-host-and-device)
4. Support for managed memory on Windows is limited. I think in this instance the support is still sufficient, but see for example here: [CUDA Unified Memory: Difference in behaviour on Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879821/cuda-unified-memory-difference-in-behaviour-on-windows-and-linux)

Comment: Unified memory support on Windows is sadly still very poor compared to Linux, i.e. no page-migration.

Comment: @paleonix Thanks, I didn't know that. I think it's still okay here since we only use it for initialization, right?

Comment: It will depend on the context of the application. As far as I understand it you get problems when you want to work on managed memory on the host and the device concurrently (different buffers) because **all** managed memory is sent to the device at kernel launch. See [Unified Memory System Requirements](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#system-requirements) and [Data Migration and Coherency](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#data-migration-and-coherency)

Comment: @Homer512 Thank you for your answer. The main issue was in my host-side vector. The image buffer was not extracted properly hence cudaMemcpy gave an Access Violation Error. But your solution helps me to work with the structure type vector and pointer within it.