# CUDA Malloc for structs with pointers to pointers

Tags: memory-management, cuda

I have a struct of the following form -

```
struct NeuralNet
{
    int num_layers;
    int *neurons_per_layer;
    double **w;
    double **b;
    double **in; // weighted sum or input pixels
    double **out;
    double **delta;
    double *targets; // one hot vector
};
```

Now, to allocate this on my host it's a pretty big function as given below -

```
    struct NeuralNet *alloc_nn(int num_layers, int neurons_per_layer[])
{

    struct NeuralNet *nn = (NeuralNet *)malloc(sizeof(struct NeuralNet));
    nn->num_layers = num_layers;
    nn->neurons_per_layer = (int *)malloc(nn->num_layers * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < num_layers; i++)
    {
        nn->neurons_per_layer[i] = neurons_per_layer[i];
    }
    nn->w = (double **)malloc((nn->num_layers - 1) * sizeof(double *));
    nn->b = (double **)malloc((nn->num_layers - 1) * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < nn->num_layers - 1; i++)
    {
        nn->w[i] = (double *)malloc((nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * (nn->neurons_per_layer[i + 1] + 1) * sizeof(double));
        nn->b[i] = (double *)malloc((nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
    }
    nn->in = (double **)malloc((nn->num_layers) * sizeof(double *));
    nn->out = (double **)malloc((nn->num_layers) * sizeof(double *));
    nn->delta = (double **)malloc((nn->num_layers) * sizeof(double *));
    nn->targets = (double *)malloc((nn->neurons_per_layer[nn->num_layers - 1] + 1) * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < nn->num_layers; i++)
    {
        nn->in[i] = (double *)malloc((nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
        nn->out[i] = (double *)malloc((nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
        nn->delta[i] = (double *)malloc((nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
    }
    return nn;
}
```

I want to allocate this memory on my GPU. My plan is to basically do all the training on the GPU and then just copy to the host. To do so, I wrote the following cudaMallocs

```
struct NeuralNet device_nn;
    device_nn.num_layers = nn->num_layers;
    cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.neurons_per_layer), (nn->num_layers) * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(device_nn.neurons_per_layer, nn->neurons_per_layer, (nn->num_layers) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Allocate memory for w, b, in, out, and delta arrays
    cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.w), (nn->num_layers - 1) * sizeof(double **));
    cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.b), (nn->num_layers - 1) * sizeof(double **));
    cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.in), nn->num_layers * sizeof(double **));
    cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.out), nn->num_layers * sizeof(double **));
    cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.delta), nn->num_layers * sizeof(double **));

    // Copy data for w, b, in, out, and delta arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < nn->num_layers - 1; ++i)
    {
        cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.w[i]), (nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * (nn->neurons_per_layer[i + 1] + 1) * sizeof(double));
        cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.b[i]), (nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
        cudaMemcpy(device_nn.w[i], nn->w[i], (nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * (nn->neurons_per_layer[i + 1] + 1) * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(device_nn.b[i], nn->b[i], (nn->neurons_per_layer[i + 1] + 1) * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nn->num_layers; ++i)
    {
        cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.in[i]), (nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
        cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.out[i]), (nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
        cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.delta[i]), (nn->neurons_per_layer[i] + 1) * sizeof(double));
    }

    // Allocate memory for targets array
    cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.targets), (nn->neurons_per_layer[nn->num_layers - 1] + 1) * sizeof(double));
```

But this give segfault over here - `cudaMalloc(&(device_nn.w), (nn->num_layers - 1) * sizeof(double **));`

Any ideas on how to do this correctly?

My host neural net is initialized like this -
`struct NeuralNet *nn = alloc_nn(numHiddenLayers + 2, neurons_per_layer); init(nn);`

Comment: Note you can use one big flatten array and compute the start-stop offset in the big flatten array. This not only reduce the number of allocation and copy but also speed up the copy since sending data in bigger chunk is usually faster. I think it also makes the code simpler and remove issues with pointers of pointers.

Comment: Why do you use `sizeof(double **)` for the failing `cudaMalloc`s (instead of using `sizeof(double *)` like on the host size) ?   Also please post a [mre].

Comment: By the way, note that double precision is rarely useful for neural network. Nowadays, they tends to even use half-precision which is often enough. Besides, double-precision is generally significantly slower then simple one. On mainstream client-side GPUs, double-precision is typically 32x-64x times slower than simple precision (when even supported). This is so slow that CPU are often faster on such GPUs.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I do the pointer to pointer as it points to the layer first and then the weight matrix, or bias vector of that layer. Changing this structure would lead to a lot of changes in the rest of the code.

Comment: You want to allocate arrays of array; always a bad idea but especially with CUDA. The array of pointers resides in device memory. The host function `cudaMalloc` cannot directly write there so it cannot initialize the inner array pointers. If you really want to do this, you have to go in steps from the inside out or use managed memory. See [Passing a struct type vector from CPU to GPU in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77837765/passing-a-struct-type-vector-from-cpu-to-gpu-in-cuda/77846385#77846385)

Comment: But really, you should not do this. Make one large allocation where the size is the sum of the sizes of all layers. You can still create an array of pointers to the positions where each layer starts in the allocation. And yeah, `double` for machine learning is silly and if you have a consumer-grade GPU, it won't have good `double` performance anyway

Comment: You can still allocate/copy/free one big chunk and then compute the pointer of pointer where each sub-pointer point on a chunk of the bigger one not to change the rest of the code. But on GPU, you should really avoid dealing with pointer of pointer anyway. On CPU this is not so critical if you do not do intensive computation based on them and the CPU code is just meant to start GPU kernels and things like this. Note that a `cudaMalloc` is significantly more expensive than a basic `malloc`.

Comment: I am now changing it to what you are suggesting. I'll also change the doubles to floats and see how it goes.

Comment: This stuff is much easier to do when using unified memory, although it doesn't make it more efficient. In fact `cudaMallocManaged()` might be even slower than `cudaMalloc()`.